# "Getline" from file doesn't read the first string of the line

Tags: c++, file-io

i have a file with a string " abc defg hij klmno " , when i am trying to read this and  modify it , the output result is  "defg hij klmno" somehow the first string is missing. any ideas?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ifstream myfile("C:\\sth.txt");
   string Ciphertext;
while (myfile>>Ciphertext)
{
    getline(myfile, Ciphertext);    
}


//some other code...
```

Comment: The Berzerko Joe indentation style is hiding a misplaced bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the first entry into `Ciphertext`, then immediately discard it and read "the rest" if the line.

```
while(myfile>>Ciphertext)
{
    getline(myfile, Ciphertext);
}
```

Try this instead:

```
while(getline(myfile, Ciphertext))
{
    // logic for each line here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
while (myfile>>Ciphertext)
{
    getline(myfile, Ciphertext);    
}
```

The expression in the `while` attempts to read the first white-space delimted string from the file into `Ciphertext`.  It succeeds, reading `abc`, so it goes into the loop where it reads a line (up to the next newline) into `Cipertext`, replacing whatever is there.  So it reads the rest of the first line `defg hij klmno`.  It then goes back and tries to read another whitespace delimeted string, but that fails, as you're now at the end of the file.  So the while loop ends, leaving `defg hij klmno` in `Ciphertext`